# Delete vpc request leaves VPC in inconsistent state(aws-java-sdk)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk

I have tried deleting vpc as -

```
private static void deleteVpc(String vpcId)
{
        DeleteVpcRequest deleteVPC = new DeleteVpcRequest();
        deleteVPC.setVpcId(vpcId);

        ec2.deleteVpc(deleteVPC);
        System.out.println("Deleted VPC"+vpcId);
    }
```

It responds successfully but when I log in to AWS console VPC is still there with #bad string attached to vpc ID (vpc-7d1bad12).  Why might this be happening ?

Answer (score 0):

7d1bad12 is a Hex string and not your normal string. I assume you gave a delete request and shortly you logged into the system and saw your VPC still existing. VPC deletion is a time consuming process and it takes time before your VPC is deleted. When the API says it returned successfully it means that the SDK was able to send the delete request successfully and this delete request is asynchronous and therefore, it returns immediately. If your VPC was empty then after some time it should go away from the AWS console.

Comment: No even after one day of deleting VPC it still shows that hex string